# Pull elements from array with property value under or over X

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a very large list of a custom class. I often need to perform a task based on only elements from the list where a custom value of the class is over or under a specific threshold.

Currently, I do something like this:

```
//Sort the customList by it's X value (sometimes ascending, sometimes descending)
customList.Sort((a, b) => b.X.CompareTo(a.X));

//Iterate through array until the X value is not within the necessary range
for (int i = 0; i < customList.Count; i++)
{
    if (customList[i].X < .5f) break;
    PerformTask(customList[i]);
}
```

This isn't a huge bottleneck, but it would be best if I can speed up this kind of task for this application (not to mention I am always wanting to learn things like this).

So the question is, is there a much faster sorting method without writing it myself and/or is there a faster way to run PerformTask on the elements meeting specific criteria without iterating over all elements?

My question might also be better asked in regards to keeping a list sorted not just when adding/removing items, but also when changing the values they are sorted on...

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: How will you define which elements match criteria without checking each element?

Comment: My question might also be better asked in regards to keeping a list sorted not just when adding/removing items, but also when changing the values they are sorted on...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting is the wrong approach here. It's O(n log n) with a very efficient algorithm. Use `Enumerable.Where`:

```
foreach (var item in customList.Where(n => n.X > 0.5f))
{
    PerformTask(item);
}
```

Comment: That is same as it implemented now - every item is enumerated (which is cannot be avoided)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Except it's O(n) instead of O(n log n).

Comment: Sorry missed part where array is sorted, +1

Comment: Because of the way I originally asked the question, I feel like I should accept this as the answer. I'll go ahead and ask the question that may be what I'd really like to know separately.

Comment: I'm going to google for more information on Enumerable.Where, but would you mind explaining how it functions vs sorting that makes it O(n)?

Comment: @TimWinter It iterates over the list once, and all it does is checks if it meets the criteria, and if so, `yield return`s it back.

Comment: @TimWinter An accurate answer can only be given if we know more about the characteristics of your data. For example, if the list changes very infrequently and the list is large and the number of items you will return is small compared to the length of the list - then you might want to keep a sorted list.

Comment: As I tried to ask a new question, while trying to explain it, I answered my own question. Since I know the values I need to search for, keeping a list of indexes pointing to my static list with values matching my requirement makes it quite simple.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I got the impression that he's repeating this task a large number of times. That would make a sorted version O(m log n) vs. unsorted at O(mn).

Comment: @JustinMorgan: If this is repeated for the same array, with the same ordering and the same limit, then it might make sense.